# Как вызвать callvirt для созданного объекта в CIL?

Tags: c#, cil

Как вызвать метод после создания объекта? Сейчас делаю вот таким образом:

```
DynamicMethod method = new DynamicMethod("test_method", typeof(List<string>), new Type[0]);
var generator = method.GetILGenerator();

var type = typeof(List<string>);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, type);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "test");
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, type.GetMethod("Add"));
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var result = (List<string>)method.Invoke(null, null);
```

Но получаю исключение

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Bad method token.
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "test");
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, type.GetMethod("Add"));
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Для `OpCodes.Newobj` нужно передавать конструктор, который нужно вызвать, а не тип, который нужно создать.

Comment: Спасибо, работает как швейцарские часы =)